# Error occurred while installing bundle

Tags: 16.04, git, ruby, gem

Following error occurred while trying to configure githubpage from my local machine:

Error Displayed:

```
An error occurred while installing ffi
(1.9.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.14'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

Running the command gem install ffi -v '1..9.14' following error occurred.

```
sudo  gem install ffi -v '1.9.14'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160930-6846-1an2in3.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.14/gem_make.out
```

Then I looked at the log file: gem_make.out which showed following error

```
sudo cat /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.3.0/ffi-    1.9.14/gem_make.out
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160930-6846-1an2in3.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Either suggest me the way to download ruby.h and add it in that particular location or help me with the right way if installation of gem.

Comment: You have to install the header files which are included in the developmental packages. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby-dev see also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Troubleshooting_the_configure

Answer (score 3):

I have had the similar problem.

> An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.14'` succeeds before bundling.

I fixed it with **`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`**.
I've found the answer [here](https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev.github.io/issues/229)

Answer (score 0):

Installing `ruby-dev` didn't solve this for me. This appears to be a known issue, see [here](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/608#issuecomment-363698071).

The fix given there (which worked for me) is:

`sudo apt install libffi-dev`